# Why would eloquent model Create or Update no longer work as expected?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

When I try to `model->create($input)` or `model->update($input)` with input passed through a commandbus (versus doing it in my controller), Laravel does not ignore the values that start with an underscore, as would be expected.

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1 no such column: _token (SQL: update "guests" set "_token" = ...

What am I doing wrong?

```
# GuestRegistrationCommandHandler.php

public function handle($command)
{
    if ($this->guest->exists($command->input['email']))
    {
        $guest = $this->guest->registerExisting($command->input);
    }
    else
    {
        $guest = $this->guest->registerNew($command->input);
    }

    $this->dispatcher->dispatch($guest->releaseEvents());

    return Redirect::to('/register/thankyou');
}


# EloquentGuestRepository.php

public function registerExisting(array $input)
{
    $guest = $this->guest->update($input);

    $this->raise(new GuestWasRegistered($guest));

    return $guest;
}
```

### Update:

I've changed around some code and now in my controller I am just excluding the input names with underscores for now.

```
# RegistrationController.php

public function store()
{
    try
    {
        $this->registration->validate(Input::all());

        $command = new GuestRegistrationCommand(Input::except('_token', '_tos'));
        $this->commandBus->execute($command);
    }

    catch(FormValidationException $e)
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($e);
    }
}
```

However, now I get the error:

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 19 column email is not unique (SQL: update
>   "guests"...

The email is not unique because the email is the same as the one I am updating with. This never gave me a problem before I tried to use a CommandBus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was not actually updating an existing model, so Eloquent was getting weird when calling `update()` on a new model.

Refactoring a bit fixed everything.

```
# RegistrationController.php

public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    try
    {
        $this->registration->validate($input);

        $command = new GuestRegistrationCommand($input);

        $this->commandBus->execute($command);

        return Redirect::to('/register/thankyou');

    }

    catch(FormValidationException $e)
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($e);
    }
}
```

-

```
# GuestRegistrationCommandHandler.php

public function handle($command)
{
    $guest = $this->guest->register($command->input);

    $this->dispatcher->dispatch($guest->releaseEvents());
}
```

The key to fixing it is the basic step of first finding an existing guest as seen below:

```
# EloquentGuestRepository.php

public function register(array $input)
{
    $guest = $this->find($input['email']);

    if (is_null($guest))
    {
        $guest = $this->guest->create($input);
    }
    else
    {
        $guest->update($input);
    }

    $this->raise(new GuestWasRegistered($this));

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using [Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment), you must declare a `$fillable` property in your model to allow fields that you want to fill in or use a `$guarded` property, for example:

```
// Only these fields will be inserted even there are more
protected $fillable = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email');
```

Also you may do the reverse using this property in your `Model`:

```
// These fields will not be inserted even
// they are provided in an array with other
protected $guarded = array('id', 'password');
```

So, the model you are creating using `create(Input::all())`, just add a `$fillable` or `$guarded` property.

Comment: I have `protected $guarded = array('id);` in my model.

Comment: If you have `$guarded = array('id)` in your model then any property without the `id` would be inserted in your model with `create` but if you use `$fillable = array('name', 'description')` instead of `$guarded = array('id)` then only `name` and `description` property will be inserted in to your model when using `create`.

Comment: I get it. The error was not a `MassAssignmentException` though. Eloquent normally ignores the fields that start with an underscore, and I couldn't figure out why it wasn't. Turns out it was a rookie mistake, I was calling `update()` on a model that didn't exist in the database.